# Dictionary returning same value for every key only when value is also an enumerable or custom

Tags: vb.net, list, dictionary, collections, ienumerable

i am a noob, so please take this question with that in mind. Here is very simple piece of code:

```
Sub main()
{
Dim m_Dictionary as new Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of String))
Dim workingList as new List(Of String)
Dim workingKey as Integer
Dim keyStash as List(Of Integer)
Dim workingDict as new Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

For i=0 to 9
    Do
      workingKey = RandomInteger()
    Loop While workingList.ContainsKey(workingKey)

    For n=0 to 4
      workingList.Add(RandomString())
    Next
    keyStash.Add(workingKey)
    workingDict.Add(workingKey, workingList)

 Next
 ' now I just want to play back the generators of random data

 For each Key As Integer in keyStash

    For each Entry as String in workingDict(Key).Value

           Line(Entry)

     Next

   Next
```

Instead of everything playing back nicely as one might expect, I am left with a fully accurate stash of keys for the dictionary. However, the values for strings inside each list instance are ALL THE SAME FOR EVERY KEY. Those values are equal to the values in the last loop of random data generation. So instead of playing back 50 uniques entries, it writes out 9 times the last loop. I looked inside - everything looks good. Get this. All lists, collections, hash-tables, all of iterated types and also custom types demonstrate this behavior. I found the solution, but it does not explain anything. Can anyone help explaining this, please!??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable that keeps the strings generated by `RandomString` is created outside the loop. Inside that loop you add continuosly new strings to the same instance and add the same list instance to every new integer key. At the end of the loop every integer key added has its value pointing to the same reference of the list. Of course they are identical....

A first fix to your code could be

```
Dim m_Dictionary as new Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of String))
Dim workingKey as Integer

For i=0 to 9

    ' Internal to the loop. so at each loop you get a new list
    ' to use for the specific key generated in the current loop
    Dim workingList as new List(Of String)

    Do
        workingKey = RandomInteger()
    Loop While m_Dictionary.ContainsKey(workingKey)

    For n=0 to 4
        workingList.Add(RandomString())
    Next
    m_Dictionary.Add(workingKey, workingList)
Next 
For each k in m_Dictionary 
    For each Entry in k.Value
        ' Line(Entry)
        Console.WriteLine("Key=" & k.Key & " Values = " & Entry)
    Next
Next
```

Please, remember to use [Option Strict ON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx), the current code treats quietly strings as if they were numbers, and this is not a good practice. Option Strict ON will force you to think twice when you work with different type of data.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand the following - the list inside the loop gets generated new values every time - I checked. But after the loop only the last version is survived in the dictionary for every key. Although the variable placement fixes it, it still makes no sense to me.

Comment: Try to think in terms of memory area. In the first loop the list is created at address 1000 and filled with 5 strings,this address is stored in the dictionary for the first key. The second loop creates a new list at address 2000 and this address is stored in the dictionary for the second key and so on. Instead, if you keep the list of string outside the loop it is always the list at memory address 1000 that is filled first with 5 strings and assigned to the fist key, the second loop adds another 5 strings to the same list (at memory address 1000) and assign at second key. And so on

Comment: So when you exit the loop all the keys in the dictionary reference the same memory address at 1000 where there is a list of string that has grown to host 50 strings.  WARNING this explanation is inaccurate on how the things really work when a managed app allocates memory for storing its data structures but I have simplified it to get to the point

Comment: Steve, that was very helpful. Would you please take a look at the edit above.

Comment: @burovik I suggest to post a new question because this seems to be a different problem. Posting a new question will be more useful because you will receive more attention than here